# updating mysql database with php rest of code works but no update

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I know the problem is not with the form, everything echo out properly.
i have been playing with this for an hour.
i have looked all over the web.
the only problem is the database is not updating.

```
if (isset($_POST["adnotes"]))
{
$adnotesnew = $_POST["adnotes"];
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE client SET adnotes = $adnotesnew
WHERE id='1'");
echo $adnotesnew;
}
```

Comment: `mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE client SET adnotes = $adnotesnew
WHERE id='1'") or die('Failed to update');`
check with this, if it outputs `Failed to update` there is something wrong with your query, check it on phpmyadmin directly. If there is no error displayed then check the `autocommit` is enabled or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
if (isset($_POST["adnotes"]))
{
    $adnotesnew = $_POST["adnotes"];
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `client` SET `adnotes` = '$adnotesnew' WHERE `id`=1");
    echo $adnotesnew;
}
```

Comment: argh suck a stupid thing to overlook ` i  tried all sorts of things with ' and " thank you